# Where does Yii Store the user in Sample Web Apps

Tags: php, yii

In the sample application created using yiic, yii has two users demo/demo and admin/admin, where does yii stored the user information? what if i wish to add more users and I would want to add it to the database myDB of table myUser, which contains two fields, user name and password?

Answer (score 0):

The user info is defined in the components/UserIdentity.pho in an array. So it's super simple at the moment. But if you have a user table, you can easily add a User model look up instead of checking in the users array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have more users in your app try using user extension for registration and management users accounts. Please follow the instruction in the link and enjoy.

> http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-user/